Unable to from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
enter image description here
Why can't I import Model successfully? The error is File "xxxxxxxx/Python/functions/EEGModels.py", line 42, in 
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras'
I am sure that the Python interpreter used to run the script is the same one where TensorFlow is installed. I also tried to reinstall tensorflow yet unable to solve the problem.

This is a hard answer because it probably involves your environment. You probably have 2 versions missmatched from keras and tensorflow. If you do a pip list while in your venv, what versions do you recieve from keras and tf??? You probably need both of them with the same number. Usually, most of the problems with this libraries, comes from versioning and dependencies.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

this is my version of packages
tensorflow                    2.16.1
tensorflow_decision_forests   1.9.0
tensorflow-hub                0.16.1
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem  0.37.0
tensorflowjs                  4.20.0
keras                         3.3.3
tf_keras                      2.16.0

I have successfully executed the code in TensorFlow 2.16.1 .Please refer
gist with the code is attached for your reference.Let me know if you are still
facing the issue
